# Xamarin Ios 15.0 failed to Launch app in WatchOS 8

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios15, xcode13, watchos-8

I was working with an project in iOS with WatchOS, once I update my WatchOS to 8.0, I am getting the following error:
Unhandled Exception:
Xamarin.Hosting.MobileDeviceException: Failed to communicate with the device. Please ensure the cable is properly connected, and try rebooting the device (error: 0xe8000065 kAMDMuxConnectError)
at Xamarin.Hosting.RealDevice.Connect () [0x00021] in /Users/mandel/Xamarin/xamarin-macios/master/maccore/tools/mlaunch/Xamarin.Hosting/Xamarin.Hosting/RealDevice.cs:57
at Xamarin.Hosting.RealDevice..ctor (System.IntPtr am_device) [0x00022] in /Users/mandel/Xamarin/xamarin-macios/master/maccore/tools/mlaunch/Xamarin.Hosting/Xamarin.Hosting/RealDevice.cs:40
at Xamarin.Hosting.DeviceDiscovery+<>c__DisplayClass23_1.b__0 () [0x00007] in /Users/mandel/Xamarin/xamarin-macios/master/maccore/tools/mlaunch/Xamarin.Hosting/Xamarin.Hosting/DeviceDiscovery.cs:225
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (System.Object state) [0x00014] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:74
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00071] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:968
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:910
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x0002b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:899
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:111
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Xamarin.Hosting.MobileDeviceException: Failed to communicate with the device. Please ensure the cable is properly connected, and try rebooting the device (error: 0xe8000065 kAMDMuxConnectError)
at Xamarin.Hosting.RealDevice.Connect () [0x00021] in /Users/mandel/Xamarin/xamarin-macios/master/maccore/tools/mlaunch/Xamarin.Hosting/Xamarin.Hosting/RealDevice.cs:57
at Xamarin.Hosting.RealDevice..ctor (System.IntPtr am_device) [0x00022] in /Users/mandel/Xamarin/xamarin-macios/master/maccore/tools/mlaunch/Xamarin.Hosting/Xamarin.Hosting/RealDevice.cs:40
at Xamarin.Hosting.DeviceDiscovery+<>c__DisplayClass23_1.b__0 () [0x00007] in /Users/mandel/Xamarin/xamarin-macios/master/maccore/tools/mlaunch/Xamarin.Hosting/Xamarin.Hosting/DeviceDiscovery.cs:225
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (System.Object state) [0x00014] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:74
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00071] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:968
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:910
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x0002b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:899
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:111

Xcode 13.0
Ios 15.0
WatchOS 8.0
Xamarin.ios 15.0.0

Comment: Try to update to the latest version.

Comment: I did, Xcode, Visual Studio, Xamarin.ios, iOS, WatchOS. Everything is on latest update. It was working perfect with the last version and as soon as I update all I am having this issue. @WenxuLi-MSFT

Comment: This link(https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/12778) may help you.